# How to find seconds LEFT or PAST the nearest hour in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, time

How do I find out number of **seconds** to the **nearest hour** for a given timestamp in Javascript?

**Examples:** (Format of the timestamp is not important)

```
2019-09-25 15:58:59 //output: 61

2019-09-25 17:00:59 //output: 59
```

Are there any JS built in functions or **moment.js** functions find out these values ?

Comment: Get the current time in seconds. Calculate the modulus from `3600`. If the result is less than 1800, that's the answer. If the result is more than 1800, subtract from 3600.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Other than making it simpler to get the number of seconds elapsed since the last hour, you don't really need momentJS or DateTime for this - it's just maths:

```js
function secondsToNearestHour(dt) {
  const secondsSinceHour = dt.unix() % 3600; //or if you prefer, you could write the slightly clumsier const secondsSinceHour = ((dt.minutes()*60) + dt.seconds());
  return (secondsSinceHour <= 1800 ? secondsSinceHour : 3600 - secondsSinceHour);
}

console.log(secondsToNearestHour(moment("2019-09-25 15:58:59"))); //expected output: 61
console.log(secondsToNearestHour(moment("2019-09-25 17:00:59"))); //expected output: 59
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

(The numbers 1800 and 3600 above, I hope it's obvious, are thus because there are 3600 seconds in one hour.)

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this with straight Javascript, using `Date.parse` to convert the time string into milliseconds. Then you can do the closest hour computation using `1800 - Math.abs(sec - 1800)`:

```js
const A = '2019-09-25 15:58:59';
const B = '2019-09-25 17:00:59';

const timeToNearestHour = (datetime) => {
  const sec = Date.parse(datetime + 'Z') / 1000 % 3600;
  return 1800 - Math.abs(sec - 1800);
}

console.log(A, timeToNearestHour(A));
console.log(B, timeToNearestHour(B));
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to extract the minutes and seconds from the timestamp, then convert both of them into seconds, and take the minimum value between the total number of seconds until the next hour, and the total number of seconds currently on "display".

```js
const A = `2019-09-25 15:58:59`;
const B = `2019-09-25 17:00:59`;

const pattern = /\d{2}:(\d{2}):(\d{2})/;

const calcTimeToHour = (timeStamp) => {
  const [_, minute, second] = timeStamp.match(pattern);
  const forwards = (60 - Number(minute) - 1) * 60 + (60 - Number(second));
  const backwards = Number(minute) * 60 + Number(second);
  return Math.min(forwards, backwards);
}

console.log(A, calcTimeToHour(A));
console.log(B, calcTimeToHour(B));
```